# SPOJ: DCOWS Why a Greedy algorithm does not work?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

Question Link: https://www.spoj.com/problems/DCOWS/

I am trying to figure out why my greedy approach to solve the above problem does not work.

Given two lists `B` & `C` with corresponding sizes of `N` & `M` with `(M > N)`, consisting of heights of bulls and cows respectively as inputs to this question, my approach to solve this problem is as follows:

- Sort both lists `B` & `C` in non-decreasing order
- Set `k = 0`
- For each item **B<sub>i</sub>** in `list B`

  - Using modified binary search on `C[k..M-N+i]` find an element **C<sub>j</sub>** at position **j**, `0<=j<=M-N` in `list C` which has the minimum absolute difference with **B<sub>i</sub>**
  - Add abs(**B<sub>i</sub>** - **C<sub>j</sub>**) to the result
  - Update `k = j + 1` for next iteration of the loop

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int my_bsearch(long *arr, int lo, int hi, long x)
{
    int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
    if (lo == mid)
    {
        if (abs(x - arr[lo]) <= abs(x - arr[hi])) return lo;
        else                  return hi;
    }

    if ((mid-1 >= 0) && (abs(x - arr[mid-1]) <= abs(x - arr[mid])))
        return my_bsearch(arr, lo, mid, x);
    else
        return my_bsearch(arr, mid, hi, x);
}

int main() {
    int M, N;
    cin >> N >> M;

    long bulls[N], cows[M];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) cin >> bulls[i];
    for (int i=0; i<M; i++) cin >> cows[i];

    sort(bulls, bulls + N);
    sort(cows, cows + M);

    long long min_val = 0, lo = 0, hi = M-N;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        lo = my_bsearch(cows, lo, hi, bulls[i]);
        min_val += abs(bulls[i] - cows[lo]);
        lo++, hi++;
    }
    cout<< min_val << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bulls 10 13 cows 11 7 if you pair 10 and 11 (greedy) then the total diff is 7, but when you pair 13 and 11 the total diff is 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in this similar question [Can we solve the “printing neatly” problem using a greedy algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976917/can-we-solve-the-printing-neatly-problem-using-a-greedy-algorithm-rather-than), a greedy solution is often led astray. Consider this data:

Bulls: 5, 5

Cows: 1, 6, 15

Your algorithm outputs minimum distance of 11 (pairs 5 to 6, and then 5 to 15). But the optimal solution is clearly 5 (pairing 5 to 1, and 5 to 6).

Comment: Thanks hatchet - however, this is the reason I loop from k to M-N+i in C - so that none of bulls remain unpaired.

Comment: @SameerLangde See my update. I didn't fully appreciate how you were handling the difference in number of bulls vs. number of cows. This one I've verified by running your code with the inputs I've proposed.